Problem on the chromatic number and independent number
Recently, I'm learning about the chromatic number of graph theory. There is a proposition in Introduction to Graph Theory by Douglas B. West:

For every graph $G$, $\chi(G) \ge \frac{n(G)}{\alpha(G)}$,with $n(G)$ is the vertex number of $G$, $\alpha(G)$ is the independent number.

I'm confused that how to get the expression of the lower bound:$\frac{n(G)}{\alpha(G)}$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Well, presumably the proposition has a proof after it explaining how to get that expression?

The proof mentioned in the book only says why the bound holds, but doesn't say anything about how the expression is figured out.

What difference is there between those two things?

Oh yes, this is what I need! Thank you!
